Is .Net Core WebAPI + .Net framework service combination leads delay in response?
we have .Net Core WebAPI calling .Net framework service for db using entity framework,
is this leads any functionality issues?
we are facing 503 issue if we hit APIs continuously to fetch so info.
please suggest, is .Net Core WebAPI + .Net framework service combination leads delay in response and ends on service unavailable(503 exeption) senario?
My opinion: Is .NET core WebAPI + .NET Core service combination is will help? need to explore this, so checking any opinions matches same.

Assuming by "calling .NET framework service" you mean "making a network request" then I think it highly unlikely that it would matter at all. Basically this question provides far too little information to really help you diagnose the issue at all.
